# Simple local html webpage to host multiple html images

Tags: html

Disclaimer: I program predominately in C/C++/Python/matlab so html is brand new to me.

I have a Matlab program that generates plots, and saves the plots into a **image1.html** file. I have many **image$$$.html** files all saved locally to my computer. For example:

- /home/username/image1.html
- /home/username/image2.html
- etc.

What I would like to do is :

1. Create a top level html page: my_awesome_page.html (this I can do with a simple hello world example)
2. I open my_awesome_page.html and it has links **Image1**, **Image2**, etc, that links to /home/username/image1.html and opens the content in /home/username/image1.html when I click on the link
3. If possible, show the contents of /home/username/image1.html on the side when I click on **Image1**, not in a new page. So I can easily navigate between image$$.html pages

These images are scientific plots and I am just trying to create a single source of all the data to make my life easier. I am not looking for anything pretty, fancy, just something simple+functional.

The more simple it is, the easier it is for me to write a program that generates the my_awesome_page.html and the links for each image.

My general question is: **where to start and what to look for?** After a quick google search I realized why I stick to C/C++; react js, node js, CSS, etc. So many things I do not know about.

Edit: This is all going to run locally on my laptop, and be opened in chrome. No intention to send this into the wild, or be able to access the webpage from outside my device.

Comment: You are probably looking for an image slider. JavaScript, CSS and HTML are enough for your case if you know exactly how many images you will load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a minimalistic crude example that should give you a pattern you can follow (you can probably write it all using `printf` in a C/C++ program):

```
<html>
  <body style="margin: 0px">
    <div style="display: flex">
      <div style="width: 20%">
        <ul style="list-style-type: none">
          <li>
            <button id="button-1">Image 1</button>
          </li>
          <li>
            <button id="button-2">Image 2</button>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <iframe id="frame" style="width: 80%; height: 100vh" src=""></iframe>
    </div>
    <script>
      const frame = document.getElementById('frame');

      document.getElementById('button-1').onclick = () =>
        (frame.src = '/home/username/image1.html');
      document.getElementById('button-2').onclick = () =>
        (frame.src = '/home/username/image2.html');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```